# Is it possible to execute command line/powershell commands from a svelte backend?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm looking to get a list of windows services on a machine on my network. Running a powershell command would be how I achieve this normally, but can I do this from a backend of a sveltekit app? Perhaps a server or api file? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute any valid code for the given backend, which by default should be NodeJS. So it is just a question of how to do that in Node.

The module `child_process` has various functions for starting new processes, e.g.

```js
// +page.server.js
const { exec } = await import('child_process')

export const load = async () =>
{
    const computerName = 'localhost'
    const stdout = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        exec(
            `powershell -command "Get-Service -ComputerName ${computerName}` +
                '| Where-Object -Property Status -EQ -Value Running' +
                '| Select-Object -Property Name"',
            (err, stdout) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(stdout)
        );
    });

    const items = stdout.split('\n')
        .map(x => x.trim())
        .filter(x => x)
        .slice(2); // removes table header

    return { items };
}
```

See also [data loading docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load).